# Factory Function JS

Tags: javascript, function

[image]

Hello, Can someone please explain me this `const {r,g,b} = this;`
Why it has no variable name, if 'this' is the variable name, to what
that 'this' pointing to?

```
function makeColor(r, g, b) {
    const color = {};
    color.r = r;
    color.g = g;
    color.b = b;
    color.rgb = function () {
        const { r, g, b } = this;
        return `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"this" is a special property of methods. When a function is called as a method of an object, as it is here, "this" refers to that object, in this case the color object, so the color.rgb() method will return the string "rgb(r,g,b)" where the r, g, and b there are the values fed to the makeColor function used to create that object.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. A follow up question... why I just cant use simply variable name instead of 'this' like  const{r,g,b }=this; === const {r,g,b}=color?

Answer (score 1):

The word 'this' is not a variable. This is a relatively new concept. they call it object destructuring syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Variable `this` doesn't even exist, this is one of the [reserved words](https://www.techonthenet.com/js/reserved_words.php) (such as `break`, `for`, `function`, `let` etc.), `this` in context you show directs to `color` constant, so in context you show `this` equals to `color` constant.

More [about `this` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).